# Swamping an image for another on click then revert back to the original

Tags: jquery, image, button, menu, swap

Hey stack overflow people!

I have a button for a drop down menu which I would like to change from a plus to a minus when clicked.

I can get the image to change to the minus but can't get it to change back to the plus.

If anyone can help that would be great, I'm using jQuery and here is my progress so far.

```
      <div class="plus-button"></div>

$('.plus-button').on('click', function(){
    $('.plus-button').removeClass('plus-button');
    $(this).addClass('minus-button');
});
```

Comment: Did you try with .toggleClass() method of jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple class names to [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). This is probably the simplest way to do it as it means that you don't have to track the current state of the element.

```js
$('.my-button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('plus-button minus-button');
});
```

```css
.plus-button {
  color: red;
}

.minus-button {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-button plus-button">BUTTON</div>
```

Comment: Super easy nicee, thank you so much i see so basically just call the second class once the empty class of .my-button is clicked.

Thank you so much :) really appreciate it mate!